# How to delete a file used by another Process

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

```
Public Class frmMainCetegory
Private Sub frmMainCetegory_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'PosDatabaseDataSet.tblItemMainCategory' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
    Me.TblItemMainCategoryTableAdapter.Fill(Me.PosDatabaseDataSet.tblItemMainCategory)
    Me.CenterToParent()
    Me.btnAddNew.Select()

End Sub

Private Sub btnAddNew_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAddNew.Click
    Try

        Me.TblItemMainCategoryBindingSource.AddNew()
        Me.txtMainCategory.Select()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub btnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click
    Try

        If Me.txtMainCategory.Text = "" Then
            MsgBox("Please Enter Main Category Name!", vbInformation)
            Exit Sub
        End If

        Me.imgMainCategoryImage.Image.Save(Application.StartupPath & "\Images\" & Me.txtMainCategory.Text & ".jpeg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)

        Me.TblItemMainCategoryBindingSource.EndEdit()
        Me.TblItemMainCategoryTableAdapter.Update(Me.PosDatabaseDataSet.tblItemMainCategory)
        Me.TblItemMainCategoryTableAdapter.Fill(Me.PosDatabaseDataSet.tblItemMainCategory)
        Me.btnAddNew.Select()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub btnDelete_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDelete.Click
    Try
        Dim MainCatName As String
        MainCatName = Me.TblItemMainCategoryDataGridView.CurrentRow.Cells("MainCategoryName").Value

        If Me.TblItemMainCategoryDataGridView.Rows.Count - 1 > 0 Then
            'check before delting, if this main category is used in sub category then It can not be deleted.
            Dim I As Integer
            I = frmSubCategories.TblItemSubCategoryTableAdapter.qryCountMainCategoryUnderSubCategory(MainCatName)
            If I > 0 Then
                MsgBox(MainCatName & " is used under Sub Category(s), Please Delete Sub Category(s) First!", vbOK)
                Exit Sub
            End If
        End If

        Me.TblItemMainCategoryBindingSource.RemoveCurrent()
        Me.TblItemMainCategoryTableAdapter.Update(Me.PosDatabaseDataSet.tblItemMainCategory)
        Me.TblItemMainCategoryTableAdapter.Fill(Me.PosDatabaseDataSet.tblItemMainCategory)

        'Delete the Main Category Image if this exists
        If System.IO.File.Exists(Application.StartupPath & "\Images\" & MainCatName & ".JPEG") Then
            System.IO.File.Delete(Application.StartupPath & "\Images\" & MainCatName & ".JPEG")
            MsgBox("Image Deleted Successfull")

        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub btnBrowse_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnBrowse.Click
    Try

        Me.OpenFileDialog1.Filter = "Bitmaps(*.JPG, *.PNG, *.JPEG, *.BMP, *.TIF, *.GIF, *.TIFF)|"
        Me.OpenFileDialog1.FileName = ""

        If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog(Me) = DialogResult.OK Then
            Dim img As String = Me.OpenFileDialog1.FileName
            Me.imgMainCategoryImage.Image = System.Drawing.Bitmap.FromFile(img)
            Me.btnSave.Select()

        Else

        End If


    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub TblItemMainCategoryDataGridView_SelectionChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TblItemMainCategoryDataGridView.SelectionChanged
    Try

        Me.imgMainCategoryImage.Image = DirectCast(Image.FromFile(Application.StartupPath & "\Images\" & Me.TblItemMainCategoryDataGridView.CurrentRow.Cells("MainCategoryName").Value & ".JPEG").Clone(), Image)
        ' Me.imgMainCategoryImage.Image = System.Drawing.Bitmap.FromFile(Application.StartupPath & "\Images\" & Me.TblItemMainCategoryDataGridView.CurrentRow.Cells("MainCategoryName").Value & ".JPEG")

    Catch ex As Exception

        Me.imgMainCategoryImage.Image = My.Resources.imgEmpty 'if image path not found then select empty image

    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub btnClose_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnClose.Click
    Me.Close()
End Sub
```

End Class

Above code give me an error message:

> image is used in another process, can't be deleted

when I delete the image file. The image is assigned to a PictureBox with selection event of the DataGridView. Since I have deleted the DataGridView row, as shown in the above code, it changes the image in the PictureBox.
Here I am unable to delete the image file related to the removed row.

Please guide and let me know if you need any further details.

Comment: Why have you now asked the same question twice? Decide which one best represents what you want to know and delete the other one.

Comment: This is a perfect example of why you should ALWAYS read the relevant documentation. If you had done so for the `FromFile` method you're calling then you'd have seen this: *"The file remains locked until the Image is disposed"*. If the file is locked until you dispose the `Image` object, obviously you need to dispose the `Image` object to delete the file. You should be disposing ANY object that supports it regardless, so you should be disposing the `Image` even if you don't want to delete the file.

Comment: `.Clone()` the Bitmap before assigning it to a Control's property. This will sever the Image from the FileStream. This: `My.Resources.imgEmpty` should be assigned to a Bitmap (it could be a Field in your Form). `My.Resources` is a factory, it creates a new Bitmap each time you call it and you never dispose of the old one. Use a single Bitmap which you dispose of  when your Form closes.

Comment: Hi jimi. Thank you! I did not find any option to delete my previous question, so i could not deleted it. Secondly, could you please help me what and where to place the dispose code as I am new to VB. NET?

Comment: If you assing a Resource's object to a Bitmap Field, dispose of it in the `Form.FormClosed` event.

Comment: Sorry, its out of my approach. Reason I'm not closing the form. I have added some data into datagrid view and selcted a image from open file dialogue. After assigning this image to picture box I save it to project directory and from there I use this image to diolay in picture box whenever the datagrid view selection is changed. And Now I want to delete that item with image saves in project folder. Here I'm not closing the form.

Comment: You will close that Form, eventually. That's when the Bitmap is disposed of. I'm talking about this: `Me.imgMainCategoryImage.Image = My.Resources.imgEmpty`. You should assing `My.Resources.imgEmpty` to a Bitmap Field. About the Bitmaps you assign to the PictureBox, you release the Stream used to load the Bitmap when you `.Clone()` the Bitmap: `Me.imgMainCategoryImage.Image = DirectCast(Image.FromFile(Application.StartupPath & "\Images\" & Me.txtMainCategory.Text & ".JPEG").Clone(), Image)`

Comment: I have shared my entire code in question, please edit wherever it is necessary. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Can somebody update me on this?

Comment: Is there anyone who can help on this?